# Run gulp on changed files in jade

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have gulp watching jade prototypes in a /source folder, structure as follows:

```
/source/prototypes/my-prototype-1/index.jade
/source/prototypes/my-prototype-2/index.jade
```

Here's the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src(['source/**/*.jade'])
    .pipe(changed('build/prototypes/', {extension: '.html'}))
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Jade task is complete' }));
});
```

The prototypes are compiled into:

```
/build/prototypes/my-prototype-1/index.jade
/build/prototypes/my-prototype-2/index.jade
```

The problem is that all prototypes are still getting re-compiled when any of them is changed. Is this perhaps because of the way I'm nesting the prototypes in folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *gulp-changed* documentation says that the first parameter is

> The destination directory. Same as you put into gulp.dest().

Try to replace the line

```js
.pipe(changed('build/prototypes/', {extension: '.html'}))
```

with

```js
.pipe(changed('build', {extension: '.html'}))
```